# Performance Center 12.00 - Error on lrd_initialize_db

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have a Vugen script that is failing at the lrd_initialize_db and giving the following error:

```
Action.c(5): lrd.c/fjInitDB: None of the library combinations specified in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file could be loaded.  Initializing for ORACLE failed
Action.c(5): lrd_initialize_db: ERROR, return-code=LRDE2015
```

I am running this script on Performance Center 12.00. I have installed Oracle 11g R2 on Windows Server 2012 (64 bit) (both controller and load generator). 
Below are the environment variables I have set:

```
ORACLE_HOME: C:\app\<user>\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2

PATH: added C:\app\srvgro-perfmon\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\BIN
```

I have verified that only a single Oracle client installed. The script appears to work locally on the lg/controller server when run using Vugen.

Below are the contents of the lrd.ini file

```
[ORACLE_WINNT]
805=lrdo32.dll+ora805.dll
816=lrdo32.dll+oci.dll
815=lrdo32.dll+oraclient8.dll
804=lrdo32.dll+ora804.dll
803=lrdo32.dll+ora803.dll
73=lrdo32.dll+ora73.dll
72=lrdo32.dll+ora72.dll
71=lrdo32.dll+orant71.dll
1100=lrdo32.dll+oraclient11.dll
```

And below is the lrd.log file

```
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "ora805.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "805" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - The specified module could not be found.

Processing continues

lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "oci.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "816" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - (null)Processing continues
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "oraclient8.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "815" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - The specified module could not be found.

Processing continues
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "ora804.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "804" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - The specified module could not be found.

Processing continues
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "ora803.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "803" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - The specified module could not be found.

Processing continues
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "ora73.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "73" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - The specified module could not be found.

Processing continues
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "ora72.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "72" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - The specified module could not be found.

Processing continues
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "orant71.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "71" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - The specified module could not be found.

Processing continues
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: Cannot load the ORACLE library (DLL), "oraclient11.dll", specified after a "+"  in the "1100" entry in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file.  - (null)Processing continues
lrd.c (24348):  lrd.c/fjInitDB: None of the library combinations specified in section [ORACLE_WINNT] in the "lrd.ini" file could be loaded.  Initializing for ORACLE failed
```

Please help me fix this

Answer (score 2):

What oracle client do you have installed?

It looks to me like:
1. you don't have any client installed or more than one
2. or you don't have the right one (32/64 versions)
3. Have the wrong data in the path variable. (more than one client installed)

Can you please answer the question above and copy/paste the ORACLE_HOME and Path variable values?

You need to install one of the instant clients from oracle:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html
a 32/64 bit version 11g or 12c
and add to the path variable:
C:\app\client\yourUserName\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin

Make sure you don't have any other client installed and make sure if you have to remove them from environment variables.

Comment: This should rather be posted as a comment. It is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I cannot directly comment to the post... I don't have 50 reputation. I was trying to help fix the problem but I need the answers... and it is an answer to the question, the problem is the "installed client" but to help fix it I need the extra data.

Comment: Undestoof but it is counter productive to other users to post comments as answers.

Comment: Appears to be a perfectly fine answer to me given the nature of the question

Comment: I have updated the question with further details. Please go through it again.

Comment: Hi, Can you copy paste the path variable entire values here?

Comment: Here are all the PATH entries: `C:\app\srvgro-perfmon\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin;C:\Program Files\EMC NetWorker\nsr\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\PCHost\bin;`

Comment: can you change this C:\app\srvgro-perfmon\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin to this: C:\app\srvgro-perfmon\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin

Comment: The application does not find the dlls because one of the path is wrong. You should check exactly the path of the client and copy paste it to both PATH and ORACLE_HOME to be the same. How many times did you installed Oracle? in the path I see you have dbhome_2 and this means you have installed it twice? change the path variable to point back to dbhome_2 and the same with oracle home variable.

Comment: dbhome_1 was an earlier installation of Oracle which was removed (the folder doesn't exist anymore). I have tried changing all the variables dbhome_2 (ORACLE_HOME and PATH) and it hasn't fixed the issue. I will correct the question (where it says dbhome_1).